# Python3: How to identify which 'text' element to scrape, and how to scrape URL via use of class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, class, tags

I'm currently scraping a website and getting the text of some details in the webpage of which I have tried to identify via Google Chrome's 'inspect' button, and I actually was able to get the text I wanted from the normal text elements.

However, I have two questions:

**1. I need to properly get the text that is associated with the proper div class.** As you can see in below code, I just entered 'h3', 'p', and 'abbr' and I was able to actually get the text, however they're not particular to a certain 'class'. I suppose it's just getting the first one it encounters, that's why in some webpages I encounter below error because it's pointing out to the wrong element.

```html
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FolderName\FileName.py", line 18, in <module>
    name1 = info2_text.text
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So I guess my real question#1 is, to avoid having above error because of misidentified 'p' paragraphs as in below example, how can I put into code to identify in terms of 'class'? I already tried `info2_text = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': '_5rgt _5nk5 _5msi'})`, however I only get above error.

```
<div class="_5rgt _5nk5 _5msi" style data-gt="{"tn":"*s"}" data-ft="{"tn":"*s"}"> == $0
 <span>
   <p>
     "Sample paragraph"
   </p>
```

**2. How to get the actual url from the `a href` element?** In below example:

```html
<div class="_52jc _5qc4 _78cz _24u0 _36xo" data-sigil="m-feed-voice-subtitle">
  <a href="sampleurl.com"></a>
```

I have tried to use `info4_url = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': '_4g34._5i2i._52we'})` however I only get to print `'None'` for this line. Or, am I looking at the wrong div class?

**Below is the actual code I am trying to use, and I want to make it as simple as possible. Thanks so much for your help!**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import re
import requests

# specify the url
url = 'https://sampleurl.com/'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
info1_header = soup.find('h3')
info2_text = soup.find('p')
info3_text = soup.find('abbr')
info4_url = soup.find('a')
# Get the data by getting its text
name = info1_header.text
name1 = info2_text.text
name2 = info3_text.text
#print text
print(name)
print(name1)
print(name2)
print(info4_url)
```

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1):

Find the paragraph/anchor in the relevant div's only:

**For the first question**:

```
 html = '''<div class="_5rgt _5nk5 _5msi" style data-gt="{"tn":"*s"}" data-ft="{"tn":"*s"}"> == $0
 <span>
   <p>
     "Sample paragraph"
   </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
parentDiv = soup.find_all("div", class_="_5rgt _5nk5 _5msi")
for elem in parentDiv:
    para = elem.find("p").text
    print(para.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
"Sample paragraph"
```

**For the second question**:

```
html = '''<div class="_52jc _5qc4 _78cz _24u0 _36xo" data-sigil="m-feed-voice-subtitle">
  <a href="sampleurl.com"></a></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for anc in soup.find_all('div', class_="_52jc _5qc4 _78cz _24u0 _36xo"):
    anchor = anc.find("a")
    print("Found the URL:", anchor['href'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Found the URL: sampleurl.com
```